Bayesian model missing outliers at cutoff in data
I am having trouble getting the model to fit. I have ED50 values of chlorophyll in corals during a heating experiment. I have 4 reef sites and 4 species of coral with ~14 corals per site-species group. The data is skewed to the right as several outliers have values at the cut-off point of 45 as their chlorophyll levels did not drop much. Below are boxplots of the data

Here is the model formula I have been generally using
  NDVIsandbox.form <- bf(ED50 | trunc(lb = 0, ub = 60) ~ Site*Species,
                  sigma = ~ Site*Species,
                  family = student(link = "identity"))

I have also tried using the skew_normal family distribution as well but it doesn't look to fit as well
Below are the priors I use for it as weak priors. I have altered many of them up and down to try and get it to fit better but it doesn't really help
  priors <- prior(normal(38.5, 3), class = 'Intercept') +
    prior(student_t(3, 0, 0.5), class = 'Intercept', dpar = 'sigma') +
    prior(normal(0.2, 2), class = 'b') +  
    prior(gamma(4, 1), class = 'nu') +
    prior(normal(0, 0.5), class = 'b', dpar = 'sigma')

I then run the model
  NDVIsandbox.brm1 <- brm(NDVIsandbox.form,
                   data = Geno_ED50s %>% filter(Type == "NDVI") %>% droplevels(),
                   prior = priors,
                   sample_prior = 'yes',
                   iter = 5000,
                   warmup = 1000,
                   chains = 3,
                   cores = 3,
                   thin = 5,
                   backend = 'cmdstanr',
                   control=list(adapt_delta=0.99),
                   refresh = 100)

I do the general trace plot checks and other metrics and they all look good but when I do a pp_check with dens_overlays it doesn't quite fit and it misses the bulk of values at 45 which was a cutoff for the ED50 values as you can see in the picture below
  NDVIsandbox.brm1 |> pp_check(type = 'dens_overlay', ndraws = 100)


I also ran a function that gives me Dharma plots on the brm model and it shows it overestimates the smaller and larger values which you can see on the dens_overlay plot above as well

I was wondering if there is anything I can do to get it to recognize the increased number of points at 45 which is there because it was a cutoff for the ED50 models. There isn't an inflated type model I could run like the model distributions between 0 and 1. I got the model to work on a glmm (below) but I would like to try and make the Bayesian work as I have other Bayesian models in the paper
modNDVI <- glmmTMB(ED50 ~ Site * Species,
                   data = Geno_ED50s %>% filter(Type =="NDVI") %>% 
                     droplevels(),
                   dispformula = ~ Site * Species, 
                   family = t_family(link = "identity"),
                   REML=TRUE)


Does cut-off = censoring? In the sense that you tried doses of up to 45 and for some that wasn't the ED50, yet? If so, censoring is the obvious solution. I'd also be tempted to model logED50. The syntax would then become logED50 | cens(isabove45) ~ ..., where isabove45 is coded as 1 (for values of ED > 45, in which case logED50 = log(45) and isabove45=1) or 0 (for values of ED50 <= 45, in which case logED50 = log(ED50) and isabove45 = 0).

@Björn, I ran dose-response curves where I set the upper bound for an ED50 at 45 degrees because I was trying to force some of the curves as some individual corals responses did not drop by 50% within my 4 temperature treatments to get the ED50 at a reasonable temperature in terms of Ocean temperature. My 4 temperature treatments ranged by 9 degrees with the lowest at ~29 and the highest at ~38 degrees. So all the values at 45 are from dose-response curves where the coral response didn't drop much and the model forced it to have an ED50 of 45 degrees.

You could just fit a version of a (sigmoid for $h\neq 1$) Emax model with the ED50, Emax, E0 and/or h (if you allow it to not be 1) allowed to be different between conditions. If you set suitable priors you can enforce a (soft-)version of your constraints.
